# How to create satellite nodes to a main node in D3.js force layout graphs

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am attempting to create satellite nodes to main graph nodes under a force layout. Each node should have **one or more corresponding satellite** node attached to it.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows the intent ( this example has a fixed  position and no force ruling the satellite node.

http://jsfiddle.net/guidoextras/zLt2sne3/1/

```
        node.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "planet_node")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.weight * 2 + 12; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1/d.rating); });


    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("class", "satellite_node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.weight * 2 + 25; })
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .style("stroke-width", "1")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", "cyan");
```

Satellite nodes should:

- be attached to the main node through a link at a fixed shorter distance. The link distance should be fixed.
- be under a force that comes form its main node (planet) and not get influenced by others ( this should probably not be an issue if the link's distance is always fixed )
- when more satellite nodes exist for the same planet node, it is expected that they can repulse each other so they don't ocupy the same position.

I am thinking that to achieve this I must:

- consider all satellite nodes as normal nodes in the same data set
- enforce the linkdistance of the links between satellite nodes and planet nodes to be shorter (or fixed) <- not sure how this can be done on specific links/nodes

Comment: So what's your question? Have you tried simply adding those "satellite" nodes to the force layout with connections to their parent?

Comment: I did, but got them influenced by the same force rules. I realized I can add a function to the force, which solves the problem. : .linkDistance( function (d) { return ( d.type == "SATELLITE" ? "10" : 120 ) } )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my finding:

1) create nodes normally to the satellite nodes

2) when creating the Link[] data between nodes, define a property "type" and set it to "planet" for links between planets and "satellite" for links between a satellite node and its planet

```
node[0] = {"name":"planet-1"}
node[1] = {"name":"satellite-to-planet-1"}
node[2] = {"name":"planet2"}
node[3] = {"name":"planet3"}

link[0] = {"source":0, "target":1, "type":"SATELLITE"}
link[1] = {"source":2, "target":3, "type":"PLANET"}
```

3) set the force layout properties as follows:

```
  this.force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(this.nodes)
  .links(this.links)
  .charge(-400)
  .linkDistance( function (d) { return ( d.type == "SATELLITE" ? "10" : 120 ) } )
  .size([this.w, this.h])
  .on("tick", tick);
```

This enforces planet-to-satellite links to be shorter than others